# Can I say "play the key role in"?

Tags: articles

If A is the main factor in successfully doing something, is it proper to use "A plays the key role in doing something" rather than "A plays a key role in doing something" (I think the latter means A is just one of important factors, instead of the most important one)? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something can play *a* key role, but it can also play *the* key role.

- Smart preparation plays a key role in giving a speech.
- Smart preparation plays the key role in giving a speech.

Your suggestion that "a key role" could be one of many other factors is good. On the other hand, "the key role" is more singular. If it were not singular, the syntax would be "the key roles are."

One way of emphasizing verbally the importance of a given factor is to pronounce *the* as *thee*. I'm not sure how that pronunciation started, but it is used quite frequently in English.

Answer (score 0):

role= a function or part performed especially in a particular operation or process

We usually say--

play  important role, play  vital role,    , play  prominent role, play  major role etc.

role= an actor's part in a film or play

He plays  role of a shopkeeper. I play  role of the villain.

It is better to use 'Smart preparation plays a key role in giving a speech.'